# I am creating a class to accept Information and place it into a 2-D array, However i am having problems with my case statement in my method

Tags: java, arrays, syntax-error

/* My I am suppose to create a 2-D array that will accept the input of 6 departments for a 4 Quarter year.  For example - " Enter Quarter's One Sales For Department One."  I Wrote this code however I cannot get my case statement to work in my "GetMessage" Method. */

```
import java.util.*;
public class EnumQuarter
  {
     static final int quarter;
     static final int First;
     static final int Second;
     static final int Third;
     static final int Forth;


     public class Quarterly

    {



        private final int ROW = 6;
        private final int COL = 4;
        private Scanner _scanner;


        Scanner  keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Quarterly(Scanner scanner)
        {
            Scanner  keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            this._scanner = scanner;
        }



/* I am getting a compiling error here, it says that a constant expression is required
for every case statement for example " case EnumQuarter.First:" This gives me that 
compiling error.  Am I missing some syntax? or am I doing something completely wrong here . */




    private String GetMessage(int quarter, int departmentNumber)
        {
            switch(quarter)
            {
                case EnumQuarter.First:
                return "Enter The First Quarterly Sales For Department [ " + departmentNumber+" ]. . . . . $ ";
                case EnumQuarter.Second:
                return "Enter a The Second Quarterly Sales For Department [ " + departmentNumber+" ]. . . . . $ ";
                case EnumQuarter.Third:
                return "Enter a The Third Quarterly Sales For Department [ " + departmentNumber+" ]. . . . . $ ";
                case EnumQuarter.Forth:
                return "Enter a The Forth Quarterly Sales For Department [ " + departmentNumber+" ]. . . . . $ ";

            }


        }



/*  I have not gotten to run this class yet but since I am new to java, I wonder if I
am creating my 2-D array properly.  Please take a look at it and comment me giving me 
advise on weather I am doing it properly or if there is a better way of doing it */



    public double GetTotalForDepartments(EnumQuarter quarter)
        {
            double [][] sales = new double [ROW][COL];
            int num = 1;
            double total = 0;

                for (int row = 0; row < ROW ; row++)
                    {
                        // This for statement is taking the column from the array in order to fill with input
                        for (int col = 0; col < COL; col++)
                            {   
                                // This will receive sale numbers from the six departments
                                System.out.print(message + "[" + num + " ]. . . . . $ ");
                                sales[row][col] = scanner.nextDouble();
                                num++;
                                // This for statement will sum each department's input
                                for (int i = 0; i < sales.length; i++);
                                total += sales[row][col];
                            }
                    }

                            return total;
        }
}   
}
```

Comment: remove this row: for (int i = 0; i < sales.length; i++);

Comment: maybe you have to convert `int quarter` from an `int` to a `EnumQuarter`

Comment: Yours is the best title I've seen on a while. In one word: self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given values to your constants.  You need to assign values to the constants before you can use them:

```
 static final int First = 0;
 static final int Second = 1;
 static final int Third = 2;
 static final int Forth = 3;
 static int quarter = First;
```

Perhaps what you wanted to do what create an `enum` instead:

```
static enum Quarter { First, Second, Third, Forth }
static Quarter quarter = Quarter.First;
```

In this case, the quarter is represented by an object of type `Quarter`, not by an `int`.